# binding validator in dotnet core configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm currently learning about dotnet core 2.0 (console app) and i'm working on configuration.
I try to use a json to configure my app and this json is bind on a class. It works fine but it seems the binder just populate with the default value if the key is not in the json file. Is there an easy way to tell the system to throw an exception in that case ?

for the moment i solved this by using reflection but maybe someone have a better solution ?

this is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class EnvironmentSettings
    {
        public int ValueOne { get; set; }
        public int ValueTwo { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EnvironmentSettings testsetting = new EnvironmentSettings();
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.SetBasePath(@"C:\Users\username\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\");
            builder.AddJsonFile("TestConfig.json", false);
            var build = builder.Build();

            var child = build.GetChildren();
            foreach(string key in typeof(EnvironmentSettings).GetProperties().Select(s=>s.Name))
            {
                if(!child.Any(item => item.Key == key))
                {
                    throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Configuration value with key '{key}' does not exist");
                }
            }

            build.Bind(testsetting);
            Console.WriteLine($"{testsetting.ValueOne} - {testsetting.ValueTwo}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

this is my json file

```
{
    "ValueOne": 1
}
```

and this is the part i wan't to change to something better if possible :

```
var child = build.GetChildren();
foreach(string key in typeof(EnvironmentSettings).GetProperties().Select(s=>s.Name))
{
    if(!child.Any(item => item.Key == key))
    {
        throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Configuration value with key '{key}' does not exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: seems there is no better solution for the moment so i made a PR https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/pull/789